# How to create and download an XML without storing it on the server

Tags: xml, vb.net, download, webforms, on-the-fly

I have an **ASP.NET Web Forms** application. I would like to create a download link to make available to the user the possibility to download an **XML file**. However the file does not have to be stored on the server.

In my **aspx** file I have the download link (placed inside a GridView):

```
 <asp:HyperLinField Text="Download" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="download.aspx?ProductId={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="ProductId">
```

In the **download.aspx.vb** page:

```
Dim productId As String = Request.QueryString("productId")
Dim xmlDoc As String = _ProductServices.GetXmlDocPerId(productId)
Dim xdoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
xdoc.LoadXml(xmlLicense)
```

Now I would like to create a file, place the XML content inside and deliver it to the user without saving it to the server. Shall I use a `MemoryStream` combined with a `StreamReader`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create the file - you already have the XML content in your `XmlDocument`, which you can directly output to the browser.

Untested example:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/xml"
Response.Clear()

xdoc.Save(Response.OutputStream)
Response.Flush()
```

Update:

To get the browser to show the *download* dialog, you simply need to add a `content-disposition` header:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=some_name.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to create the file because I want the user to download the XML file and not just view it in the browser

Comment: @CiccioMiami - You can still have the download dialog come up without having to create a file. You will need to use the [`Content-Disposition` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) as well, but no need to actually create a file on disk.

Comment: thanks, the download works but then the xml has parsing errors...if I use the method in the answer below the xml is parsed correctly but I do not have the download prompt...

Comment: @CiccioMiami - That description is not very helpful. Perhaps you can ask another question and explain the parsing errors in it.

Comment: I check the XML file and there is also the source of the page inside the document. I guess Response.Clear should do clear the stream output but actually it does not...

Comment: Ok I understood the problem, just use 'Response.End()' instead of 'Response.Flush()'

Answer (score 4):

It can be as simple as:

```
Private Sub SendResults()
         'Write the XML for the DataSet.
         Page.Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
         Page.Response.Output.Write(xmlContentAsString)
         Page.Response.End()
    End Sub
```

Essentially, you change the response output type, and pass to the output the xmldocument content.  You don't actually create a file in the system, but instead stream the response to the client.

Comment: Thanks, does your code display the download prompt to the user or simply displays the xml content?

Comment: Good question.  I believe it leaves it up to the browser to infer whether it can load or not.  By default, it would load it in the browser.  But there is another content type you can use to require it to download a file: https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php/70959-HTTP-Headers-to-force-file-to-download-rather-than-auto-open.  By using this, you may be able to have it download as a file if that is your desire.  You would have to give a disposition with a file name as mentioned in that link.